# ES6 Classes to extend Mongoose Model?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ecmascript-6

I am trying to create a class which represents a User and I want it to inherit the methods of the mongoose class which has the ability to find, save, delete etc.

I am trying to extend the mongoose model by essentially doing the following: `class User extends Mongoose.model('User', UserSchema) {}`

My actual code looks like this:

```
import { Mongoose } from '../config';
const Schema = Mongoose.Schema;

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    email: { type: String, default: '' },
    firstName: { type: String, default: '' },
    lastName: { type: String, default: '' },
    facebookId: { type: String, default: '' },
    payments: { type: Array, default: [] }
});

const MongoUser = Mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

class User extends MongoUser {

    constructor(data) {
        super();
    this.email;
    this.firstName;
    this.lastName;
    this.facebookId;
    this.payments;
  }

  save(){

  }

  findUser(data){

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        super.findOne(data, (err, user) => {

                if(err) {
                    console.log("err", err)
                    reject({err: err});
                }

              if(!user) {
                console.log("No user found")
                reject('No user found');
              }

              if(user){
                console.log("user", user)
                console.log("this", this)

                  this._set(user)

                    resolve(this);
              }

            });

        })

  }

  _set(user){
    this.email = user.email;
    this.firstName = user.firstName;
    this.lastName = user.lastName;
    this.facebookId = user.facebookId;
    this.payments = user.payments;
    return;
  }

}

export default User;
```

You will see I am trying to call a method of the parent class `super.findOne()` but am getting an error `[TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined]` which has stumped me.

No stack trace but the error is getting caught in the following try / catch:

```
exports.findUser = async (req, res) => {

    let id = '58ad46dfb558dfe00efa9b02';

    const user = new User();

    try{
        const loggedInUser = await user.findUser({_id: id});
        res.send(loggedInUser);
    }catch(e){
        console.log("e", e)
        res.send(e)
    }   
}
```

which is getting called from my route:

```
router.get('/:userID', userController.findUser);
```

Am I on the right track or is my method of trying to extend a mongoose model way off?

Comment: Does your `TypeError` come with a stack trace?

Comment: @AlexMcMillan no stack trace but have updated my question with a trace of where the function is called from

Comment: Why `super.findOne`? It wasn't overridden, it's `this`. I'm not really sure if extending a model is a good idea. Using schema classes for inheritance like `class FooSchema extends mongoose.Schema {...}; mongoose.schema('foo', new FooSchema)` may work, on the other hand.

Comment: @estus You're right that the function wasn't overwritten. When I use this, I get `TypeError: _this2.findOne is not a function` which is perhaps relates back to your comment about extending the model is not such a good idea. I will try with your suggestion using the schema class for inheritance. Thanks

Comment: @Stretch0 I think you needed to .bind(this) to findOne, so it knows its able to access variables on this for your child class 'User'. So I believe you would do super.findOne.bind(this)(data,()=>{})